# JsDoc, ES6 and @param {Constructor}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc

I am trying to use JsDoc to document es6 classes. Can't believe that you can't pass a class as a parameter (a class type, not an instance type).

I've been trying things but can't get this simple code to work so that JsDoc doesn't throw me some warnings.

I can't get it to work unless I create a @typedef for each of my classes, then add manually all own and inherited members to it. Can't even do a mixin!

Has anyone succeeded in passing a constructor/class parameter? So that JsDoc be in the static context, not the instance context?

```
/**
 * @class A
 */
class A {

    /**
     * @static
     */
    static helloFromClassA(){
    }
}

/**
 * @class B
 * @extends A
 */
class B extends A{

    /**
     * @static
     */
    static helloFromClassB(){
    }
}

/**
 * Class as object
 * @param {A} ClassArgument
 */
function fn1(ClassArgument){
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassA(); // Unresolved function or method helloFromClassA
    // Does not work because ClassArgument is interpreted as an
    // instance of A, not A's constructor
}

/**
 * // Class as function
 * @param {Function} ClassArgument
 */
function fn2(ClassArgument){
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassA(); // Unresolved function or method helloFromClassA
    // Does not work because ClassArgument is interpreted as an
    // empty function, not A's constructor
}

/**
 * // Type definition
 * @typedef {Object} AClass
 * @property {Function} helloFromClassA
 * @property {Function} super
 */

/**
 * // Trying to mixin the AClass
 * @typedef {Object} BClass
 * @property {Function} helloFromClassB
 * @mixes {AClass}
 * @mixes {A}
 */

/**
 * // Adding manually all members
 * @typedef {Object} BClass2
 * @property {Function} helloFromClassB
 * @property {Function} helloFromClassA
 */

/**
 * @param {BClass} ClassArgument
 */
function fn3(ClassArgument){
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassA(); // Unresolved function or method helloFromClassA
    // Does not work because the BClass typedef does not take
    // into account the mixin from AClass, nor from A
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassB(); // No warming
}

/**
 * @param {BClass2} ClassArgument
 */
function fn4(ClassArgument){
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassA(); // No Warning
    ClassArgument.helloFromClassB(); // No warming
    // Works because we manually defined the typedef with all own
    // and inherited properties. It's a drag.
}


fn1(B);

fn2(B);

fn3(B);

fn4(B);
```

jsDoc issue : https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1088

Comment: You've declared those methods as `static` - calling them on an instance will work, but imo it's a bit of an odd use of the keyword.

Comment: What do you mean? ES6 has the static keyword that allows you to declare methods on the constructor rather than on the prototype. These are **static** methods. And I'm not trying to call them on an instance, I'm calling on the constructor. The issue here is that JsDoc doesn't allow you to declare a parameter as a constructor (a type), it only allows you to declare a parameter as an instance.

Comment: I see. I incorrectly assumed that val was an instance rather than a reference to the function

Comment: Yeah I thought that, so I updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

I've been running into same issue with auto-completion in WebStorm multiple times. While it looks like currently there is no straight-forward way in jsdoc to say that parameter is a reference to a constructor (not to an instance), there is a suggestion from JetBrains team to implement something like @param {typeof Constructor} (where typeof is from typescript) or @param {Constructor.} that was [suggested](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/lIxWHYQuTRk) by closure compiler team. You can vote for following issue to get your main concern with WebStorm autocompletion resolved - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17325

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Code, you can specify

```
@param {function(new:MyClass, SomeArgType, SecondArgType, etc...)}
```

I'm not sure what spec that syntax comes from or who else supports it, but it Works For Me.

Answer (score 1):

typescript and google closure both support `{typeof SomeClass}` for referencing a class as a type (not a class instance). Unfortunately jsdoc doesn't support that syntax and will fail to compile it (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1349).

Because I want to type-checking my JavaScript with typescript and also want to generate documentation I made this jsdoc plugin to transform expressions like `{typeof SomeClass}` into `{Class<SomeClass>}` so I can have both things: https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/jsdoc-typeof-plugin

Comment: It is also understood by WebStorm, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10214